# Regarding conditional build (Macro) in C/C++/QT

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake, integration

I would like to know the common (recommended) way to select which to build when I do a **conditional build**.

---

So For example, there are two files that could be selected.

**Condition 1:**

```
class Page : QWebPage {
    public:
        string test1;
}
```

**Condition 2:**

```
class EnginePage : QWebEnginePage {
    public:
        string test1;
        string test2;
}
```

---

The most common way that I saw is using makefile-related file similar to below:

**File related to Makefile:**

```
Source     += \
               one.h \
               two.h \
               three.h \
               four.h \

#if (one_defined)
    Source  += Page.h
#else
    Source  += EnginePage.h
#end
```

but (Here is the **Question**) I would like to know whether similar to this (using one single file instead of two) is possible and recommended:

**Single file (Condition 1 + Condition 2):**

```
#if (one_defined)
    class Page : QWebPage
#else 
    class EnginePage : QWebEnginePage {
#endif

    public:
        string test1;

#if (one_defined)
        string test2;
#endif
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#cmakedefine CMAKE_VAR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html?highlight=cmakedefine) in a .h file.

[`CONFIGURE_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html) will automatically replace it by `#define CMAKE_VAR` or `/* #undef CMAKE_VAR*/`
depending on whether `CMAKE_VAR` is set in CMake or not.

**A concrete example :**

Let's say you have a CMake variable that is called `QWebPage_Defined` that is equal to true if QWebPage is defined.

You'll have then to create a file (e.g. `configure.h.in`) that contains :

```
#cmakedefine QWebPage_Defined
```

In your CMake script you will call the [`CONFIGURE_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html) function :

```
configure_file("configure.h.in", "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/configure.h")
```

And then in your header :

```
#include "configure.h" // Include the file

#ifdef QWebPage_Defined // Warning : use #ifdef and not #if
    class Page : QWebPage
#else 
    class EnginePage : QWebEnginePage {
#endif

    public:
        string test1;

#ifdef QWebPage_Defined // Warning : use #ifdef and not #if
        string test2;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Could the match between the class name and the actual file name be ignored?

Comment: Yes you can ignore this in c++. If you really need to have a file name based on your class name can look at the [copy](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/file.html) function of CMake, but i don't recommend it.